# Display text under the icon on a single line

Tags: html, css

I already got them to display on a single line, but the text is not displaying under the icon but rather beside it.

[image]

How can I display the text under the icon?

This is my HTML

```
<div class="top_categories">
    <div class="cat_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_text">
        Pottery & Ceramics
    </div>

    <div class="cat_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-hand-paper-o fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_text">
         Handcrafts
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.top_categories {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}
.cat_icon {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.cat_text {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Where's your html/css/js for displaying icons?

Comment: I'm using FontAwesome for the icons.

Comment: Please add your FontAwesome code to your question. There is currently not enough data to properly answer.

Comment: Or better yet, can you as well post the rendered html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap each group in a div, and style `float:left;padding:5px 10px;` *Note that the padding just keeps them from being snug up beside one another*

Note that when you float a div, it is removed from the HTML "flow" -- meaning that it now takes zero vertical space on page.  To fix this, wrap that entire bit of code in another div, and style it `overflow:_____` (hidden or auto), comme ca:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="overflow:auto">
    //the other HTML from the example
</div>
```

Whups - you've already got such a wrapping div, called `.top_categories`, so I added that to the css.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uo6mob9w/3/)</kbd>

```css
.top_categories {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
}
.cat_icon {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.cat_text {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.my-group{
  float:left;
  xxborder:1px solid red;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.top_categories{overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top_categories">
  <div class="my-group">
    <div class="cat_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_text">
        Pottery & Ceramics
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="my-group">
    <div class="cat_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-hand-paper-o fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_text">
         Handcrafts
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put both text and icon in a wrapper and give those elements a `display: inline-block`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cat_icon">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_text">
        Pottery & Ceramics
    </div>
</div>



.wrapper {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

And then you can remove the from the `cat-icon` and `cat-text` classes.

I put the code in a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hyx5hsa2/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each icon and text with an extra `<div>` (display: inline-block), then change display on icon and text to 'block'.